# does batch program support any ascii characters or is there's a way to create encoder and decoder program with another tools?

Tags: batch-file, character-encoding, ascii

i wrote batch encoder and decoder from adrianvdh and customize some of the text string input, but the decoder one aren't working, because i put special symbols inside there.

here's the string of the encoder

```
@echo off
setlocal  ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
title Encrypt Taro
color 4
:mainmenu
set savefile=on
::set Encrypt=Nothing
(set CHAR[A]=Ἁ) & (set CHAR[B]=Ằ) & (set CHAR[C]=Å) & (set CHAR[D]=Ȧ) & (set CHAR[E]=ᾉ)
(set CHAR[F]=ᾎ) & (set CHAR[G]=Ἇ) & (set CHAR[H]=Ǟ) & (set CHAR[I]=Ặ) & (set CHAR[J]=Ậ)
(set CHAR[K]=Ᾰ) & (set CHAR[L]=Ἄ) & (set CHAR[M]=ᾌ) & (set CHAR[N]=ᾋ) & (set CHAR[O]=ᾊ)
(set CHAR[P]=Ấ) & (set CHAR[Q]=Ἃ) & (set CHAR[R]=Ả) & (set CHAR[S]=Ⱥ) & (set CHAR[T]=Ắ)
(set CHAR[U]=Ά) & (set CHAR[V]=Ȁ) & (set CHAR[W]=Ẫ) & (set CHAR[X]=Ᾱ) & (set CHAR[Y]=Ä)
(set CHAR[Z]=Ḁ) & (set CHAR[1]=1) & (set CHAR[2]=2) & (set CHAR[3]=3) & (set CHAR[4]=4)
(set CHAR[5]=5) & (set CHAR[6]=6) & (set CHAR[7]=7) & (set CHAR[8]=8) & (set CHAR[9]=9)
(set CHAR[0]=) & (set CHAR[.]=.) & (set CHAR[,]=,) & (set CHAR[ ]= )
echo Enter a string to encrypt:
set /p Encrypt=
cls
set Encrypt2=%Encrypt%
set "EncryptOut="
:encrypt2
set char=%Encrypt2:~0,1%
set Encrypt2=%Encrypt2:~1%
set EncryptOut=%EncryptOut%!CHAR[%char%]!
if not "%Encrypt2%"=="" goto encrypt2
echo Input string: %Encrypt%
echo.
echo Output string: %EncryptOut%
set string=%EncryptOut%
set temp_str=%string%
set str_len=0
:lengthloop
if defined temp_str (
set temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
set /A str_len += 1
goto lengthloop )
echo.
echo Output string is %str_len% characters long!
echo.
echo Consider to check the recent "encryptedtaro.txt" if the result are messed up.
if "%savefile%"=="on" echo.%EncryptOut%>>%~d0%~p0encryptedtaro.txt
echo.
pause
cls
goto mainmenu
```

and here's the decoder

```
@echo off
setlocal  ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
title Decrypt Taro
color 4
:mainmenu
set savefile=on
::set Decrypt=Nothing
(set CHAR[Ἁ]=A) & (set CHAR[Ằ]=B) & (set CHAR[Å]=C) & (set CHAR[Ȧ]=D) & (set CHAR[ᾉ]=E)
(set CHAR[ᾎ]=F) & (set CHAR[Ἇ]=G) & (set CHAR[Ǟ]=H) & (set CHAR[Ặ]=I) & (set CHAR[Ậ]=J)
(set CHAR[Ᾰ]=K) & (set CHAR[Ἄ]=L) & (set CHAR[ᾌ]=M) & (set CHAR[ᾋ]=N) & (set CHAR[ᾊ]=O)
(set CHAR[Ấ]=P) & (set CHAR[Ἃ]=Q) & (set CHAR[Ả]=R) & (set CHAR[Ⱥ]=S) & (set CHAR[Ắ]=T)
(set CHAR[Ά]=U) & (set CHAR[Ȁ]=V) & (set CHAR[Ẫ]=W) & (set CHAR[Ᾱ]=X) & (set CHAR[Ä]=Y)
(set CHAR[Ḁ]=Z) & (set CHAR[1]=1) & (set CHAR[2]=2) & (set CHAR[3]=3) & (set CHAR[4]=4)
(set CHAR[5]=5) & (set CHAR[6]=6) & (set CHAR[7]=7) & (set CHAR[8]=8) & (set CHAR[9]=9)
(set CHAR[0]=0) & (set CHAR[.]=.) & (set CHAR[,]=,) & (set CHAR[ ]= )
echo Enter a string to decrypt:
set /p Decrypt=
cls
set Decrypt2=%Decrypt%
set "DecryptOut="
:decrypt2
set char=%Decrypt2:~0,1%
set Decrypt2=%Decrypt2:~1%
set DecryptOut=%DecryptOut%!CHAR[%char%]!
if not "%Decrypt2%"=="" goto decrypt2
echo Input string: %Decrypt%
echo.
echo Output string: %DecryptOut%
set string=%DecryptOut%
set temp_str=%string%
set str_len=0
:lengthloop
if defined temp_str (
set temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
set /A str_len += 1
goto lengthloop )
echo.
echo Output string is %str_len% characters long!
echo.
echo Consider to check the recent "decryptedtaro.txt" if the result are messed up.
if "%savefile%"=="on" echo.%DecryptOut%>>%~d0%~p0decryptedtaro.txt
echo.
pause
cls
goto mainmenu
```

indeed i make the numbers blank because unnecessary.[tested program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y30ri.png)

i need help with any string which make the output string in the "Decode" isnt blank. i would imagine it will showed with the right decrypted text, anyone can help? or fix the batch code...

Comment: It looks like the question is caused by missing knowledge about character encoding in general and which one is used by text editors on writing a batch file and which one is used by `cmd.exe` on processing a batch file. I recommend to read [Batch Not Reading Foreign Characters in Windows Folder Names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76022079/3074564) and [Why are Danish characters not displayed as in text editor on executing batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052862/3074564) with all the referenced links to Wikipedia and Microsoft pages to get the required knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from different encodings used by 1) CMD and 2) anything Windows.

You can easily reproduce the phenomenon by creating a file name containing non-ASCII characters and listing the in cmd using the `dir` command.

This raises the question how you created above batch files. In a DOS-editor or in a Windows editor? I recommend Notepad++ (or similar editors with encoding support) to verify the encoding of your batch files. Note that in such editors you can switch the encodings so that the same byte sequence is interpreted as different text according to the selected code page.

In your encoder generates data which cannot be decoded, it is probably because the encoded result cannot be processed in the cmd codepage.